# Canon c1028i - Scan to Shared Folder

Tags: printer, scanning

I have a Canon c1028i and I need to know if it's possible to scan documents to a shared folder.

Thanks.

Comment: welcome to superuser: what research have you done, checked canon website,etc. Where you scan to is generally asked at scanning and may show in the dialog window. [Ask] and [Help] may prove useful again welcome to superuser.

Comment: I want to configure personal folders for that printer. I've checked the manual and I could not find anything about it.

Comment: Try reading through the [HTML manual](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/products/imagerunner/imagerunner-c1028i.aspx?type=manuals&manualid=tcm:14-1624772).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Canon support page](http://helpdesk.copiersnw.com/article.php?id=110) on setting up scan-to-folder on ImageRunner products via its web interface.

Start by browsing to the printer's IP address. Click the Address button and select an Address Book. Create a New Address, select SMB as the protocol, select your file type for the scans, enter Host Name and File Path, and a User Name and Password to access that folder.

The C1028i is part of the ImageRunner product range, so it should apply to your printer, although details may differ.